# How to use html2canvas to print web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html2canvas

I want to have my page print exactly like it's shown on screen, and found a script called html2canvas: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html

See my implementation below.

I have 2 problems:

1. When I click the print button, Chrome shows the print dialog, but the page is shown 2 times - first the regular print version, and after that html2canvas render. Obviously I don't need the regular print... I tried to hide 'body', but that didn't help.

(Edit: fixed this one: 2. I don't want divs with "#hidden-print" show up on the render. But even when I hide it like shown in my code, it still shows up. Anyone knows how to make sure this is not shown in the render? )

```
    $('#print').on('click', function(){

        html2canvas(document.body, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                $('#hidden-print').hide();
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                window.print();
                $('canvas').remove();
                $('#hidden-print').show();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: you hide after render, but that doesn't change what's been rendered. hide them before you call html2canvas()

Comment: Oops, I was refering to an ID not class! I put $('.hidden-print').hide(); before calling html2canvas, and that solved problem number 2!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between appending the canvas and printing, add a style rule to hide all descendents of body except the canvas, not the body element itself. Obviously don't forget to remove it afterwards.

```
var hide = $('<style>').html('body *:not(canvas) { display: none !important; }').appendTo(document.head);
... // print
hide.remove();
```